# Best pratice to put the JavaScript/jQuery binding code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know what is the best pratice to put the JavaScript/jQuery "binding to events" code.

If you have a `html input button` and that you want to bind a jQuery event on it, is it better to call method in a JavaScript file that you already loaded that wil bind the events for the form. Something like `MyFormManagement.BindEvents()` or to put a `<script>` tag with

```
$(function(){ //Document ready.
  $("input.myButton").click(function(){
    //some code...
  });
});
```

Which one do you think is the most logical ? Or do you have another method to suggest ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to go with the javascript file since you will have all the events in 1 common place. Also, it will be good for reusing any common methods or events. But again, there may be *certain* cases where you might want to write javascript in the control directly.

Comment: Do you have an example of these certain cases ? And is it a bad pratice to put javascript directly in the html file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create ONE JavaScript file with an Object `Page` that contains the name of all my pages.

In each one of my pages, I put some code like :

```
$(function(){
    Page.TheNameOfMyPage.Init(); // The init method will bind all my events
});
```

So, even if there's some JavaScript code in my html pages, it is still grouped in one place an it is easy to call.